# How to raise a number's power using the Math Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having troubles raising the power of a number. I'm raising x number by 3 by this code, however I'm having errors. a doesn't exist in the current context

```
 public double Power(double a)
    {
       double equals = Math.Pow(a, 3);
       textBox1.Text = a.ToString();
        return equals;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(equals);
       Power(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: write- **MessageBox.Show(Power(a).ToString());**

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what errors you are getting? We can only help if you explain exactly what is the problem.

Comment: a doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: You have to define a in button1_Click

Comment: what is the value you want to raise to power here ?

Answer (score 0):

variable equals does not exist in the scope of button1_Click -  it is a local variable in scope of Power. Scopes are defined by { } ,whatever variable you create will only exist and be accesable in its scope. This is quite simple concept, read some more c# fundaments onlie. Try this code:

```
public double Power(double a)
    {
        double equals = Math.Pow(a, 3);
        return equals;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var a=100;
         var res= Power(a);
         textBox1.Text = res.ToString();
         MessageBox.Show(res);
    }
}
```